# GeoJSON to SVG, keeping properties (mapshaper)

Tags: geojson, convert, svg

I'd like to include GeoJSON values from an overpass-turbo query (`features[0].properties.name`) as attribute of the resulting SVG path.

Using https://mapshaper.org/, the default includes the sibling `@id:"relation/12345"` as e.g. `id="relation/12345".

While I am reading https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper/wiki/Command-Reference, does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If (on the web app) you add `id-field=FOO` then you'll get SVG with field `FOO` from your data in the `id` attribute.

You can also add `svg-data=BAR` to get field `BAR` written to a data attribute.

Using a test dataset with `FIPS` and `NAME` fields, and using `id-field=FIPS svg-data=NAME` I get path elements like this:

```
<path d="M 242.87 11.24 241.5 32.55 262.41 67.45 291.19 93.98
 307.29 137.8 292.41 145.7 252.84 138.94 233.05 145.25 237.47 
 177.85 164.98 217.71 110.45 193.78 67.01 152.86 1 121.69 27.15
 72.89 24.39 43.88 44.44 1 242.87 11.24 Z" 
 id="37009" data-name="Ashe"/>
```

These options can also be passed on the command line `mapshaper` as something like `mapshaper -id-field=FOO -svg-data=BAR [etc]` (untested)

Comment: Just figured out `svg-data=name` myself ;-)